# ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation .... in minimize.scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, minimize

I am trying to solve this integer nonlinear optimization with two constraints, but it gives me the following error.

ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity

I don't know what I should do.

Thanks for your help.

```
from ypstruct import structure
import numpy as np
import xlrd
from scipy.optimize import minimize
# empty individuals
                     #T        A       T       A     T     A   . . . .
input_data= np.array([[0.009, 0.001, 0.001, 0.009, 0.001, 0.009, 0.001, 0.009, 0.001, 0.001, 0.0002, 0.0002, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.009, 0.005, 0.001],
                     [0.05, 0.05, 0.12, 0.12, 0.15, 0.15, 0.3, 0.3, 0.02, 0.02, 0.18, 0.18, 0.2, 0.2, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01],
                     [60, 40, 60, 40, 60, 40, 60, 40, 60, 40, 60, 40, 60, 40, 60, 40, 60, 40],   
                     [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30],  # 
                     [2000,2000,1992,1992,1965,1965,1976,1976,1979,1979,1982,1982,1984,1984,1994,1994,1991,2006],
                     [5,5,3,3,8,8,8,8,10,10,12,12,11,11,1  ,1, 1,  1]])
ngroup = 9 ; limit_per_year=9 ; starting_year = 2000

C_capital = np.zeros(ngroup*2); C_sudden_replace = np.zeros(ngroup*2)
C_Gain_Power = np.zeros(ngroup*2); penalty=np.zeros(ngroup*2)
finalcost =np.zeros(ngroup*2)
X= np.array([32,31,36,38,49,44,54,54,44,45,34,34,24,24,38,85,45,54])
def objective (X):
   discount_rate= 0.04; TOTAL_COST=0
   penalti= 5
   for i in range(ngroup*2):
       C_capital[i]= (X[i]/((1+X[i])**discount_rate))
       C_sudden_replace[i] =(np.exp(-input_data[1,i]*X[i]))*input_data[2,i]
       C_Gain_Power[i] = (50 - X[i])* input_data[1,i]
       penalty[i] = 0
       if i % 2 ==1:
           penalty[i]= penalti*(abs((X[i]+input_data[4,i]-(X[i-1]+input_data[4,i]))))

       finalcost[i] = C_capital[i] + C_sudden_replace[i] + C_Gain_Power[i] + penalty[i]
       TOTAL_COST=TOTAL_COST+ finalcost[i]

   return TOTAL_COST

COSTOBJ = objective(X)

print(COSTOBJ)
```

Here is the first constraint.

```
def constraint1(X):

    matrix1= np.zeros([ngroup*2,12])

    for i in range(ngroup*2):
        d=0
        for j in range(12):
            if j<= input_data[5,i]:
               matrix1[i,j]=input_data[4,i]+X[i]+d
               d=d+1
    #print(matrix1)
    a1=int(np.min(matrix1[np.nonzero(matrix1)]))
    a2=int(np.max(matrix1[np.nonzero(matrix1)]))
    matrix2=np.zeros((1 ,int(a2-a1)+1))
    #print(matrix2)
    b=0
    for i in range(a1, a2+1):
        matrix2[0,b]=np.count_nonzero(matrix1 == i)
        b=b+1
    sortir1= int(np.max(matrix2[np.nonzero(matrix2)]))
    return limit_per_year-sortir1

CONS1= constraint1(X)
print(CONS1)
```

Here is the second constraint.

```
def constraint2(X):
    matrix1= np.zeros([ngroup*2,12])
    for i in range(ngroup*2):
        d=0
        for j in range(12):
            if j<= input_data[5,i]:
               matrix1[i,j]=input_data[4,i]+X[i]+d
               d=d+1
    #print(matrix1)
    sortir= int(np.min(matrix1[:, 0]))
    return sortir-starting_year
CONS2= constraint2(X)

print(CONS2)
```

Below, we have the optimization line, however, it gives an error.

```
cons1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1}
cons2 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint2}

cons=[cons1,cons2]
sol= minimize(objective,X ,method='SLSQP', constraints=cons)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it's worth mentioning that `scipy.optimize.minimize` can't solve integer optimization problems. Note also that expressions like `int(min(x))` or `abs(x)` aren't differentiable and thus violate the mathematical assumptions of the algorithms used under the hood of `minimize`.

Comment: Thank you, 
How can I replace them?